# how to parse this custom xml in android using xmlpullparser

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

I've got this xml:

```
  <cars>
   <a b="car" c="blue">

    <x year="01"/>
    <x year="03"/>

   </a>

   <a b="truck" c="red">
    <x year="04"/>
    <x year="85"/>
   </a>

</cars>
```

And I want to parse to an object (arraylist) like this:

```
01:["car", "blue", "01, 03"]

02:["truck", "red", "04, 85"]
```

Notice that the two year atrributes goes together in the same String. That's what I can not figure out.

The parser I'm using is the android native XMLPullParser

I cannot change XML format but I could use another android compatible parser if it's worth it.

If it's not clear it has to fit on an class like this:

```
private String car;
private String color;
private String years;


public ClassVehicle(String aCar, String c, String ys) {
    this.orden = aCar;
    this.intext = c;
    this.lugar = ys;


}

 getters & setters toString() and so on
```

the final result will as many arraylists(objects) as cars:

```
 ArrayList<ClassCar> oCars = new ArrayList<ClassCar>();

oCars.add(new ClassCar(car, color, years));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snippet is NOT XML… See [Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.1 (Second Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#sec-well-formed).

- c attribute values are not closed.
- x tag are not closed.
- You have multiple root…

If these are typos, you should correct that and I'll check if I can provide a real answer…

As a responsible programmer, don't use that format but rather migrate the data to a well-defined format but not bother to use this kind of corrupted format on a client application.

**Update**

Here is a quick-and-dirty implementation (using my own Vehicle POJO):

```
public class Butelo extends Activity
{
    public static String TAG = "SO Butelo";

    public static List<Vehicle> vehicles = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            xpp.setInput( new StringReader ( "<cars><a b=\"car\" c=\"blue\"><x year=\"01\"/><x year=\"03\"/></a><a b=\"truck\" c=\"red\"><x year=\"04\"/><x year=\"85\"/></a></cars>") );

            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            boolean done = false;

            Vehicle currentVehicle = null;

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT && !done) {

                String name = null;
                switch (eventType) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                        vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
                        break;
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    name = xpp.getName();
                        if (name.equals("a")){
                            currentVehicle = new Vehicle();
                            currentVehicle.setType(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "b"));
                            currentVehicle.setColor(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "c"));
                        } else if (name.equals("x")) {
                            currentVehicle.appendToYears(xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "year"));
                        }
                    break;
                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    name = xpp.getName();
                    if (name.equals("a")){
                            vehicles.add(currentVehicle);
                        }
                    break;
                }
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "", e.fillInStackTrace());
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "", e.fillInStackTrace());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "", e.fillInStackTrace());
        }

        for(int i=0;i<vehicles.size();i++) {
            Vehicle vehicle = vehicles.get(i);
            Log.v(TAG, vehicle.toString());
        }

    }

    private class Vehicle {
        private String mType;
        private String mColor;
        private String mYears = "";

        void setType(String type) { mType = type; }
        String getType() { return mType; }
        void setColor(String color) { mColor = color; }
        String getColor() { return mColor; }
        void appendToYears(String year) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(mYears);

            if (!mYears.equals("")) {
                sb.append(", ");
            }
            sb.append(year);
            mYears = sb.toString();
        }
        String getYears() { return mYears; }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[\"");
            sb.append(mType);
            sb.append("\", \"");
            sb.append(mColor);
            sb.append("\", \"");
                sb.append(mYears);
            sb.append("\"]");

            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

That's just to put you on your own way…

Comment: well is a snipett I'll edit, It was only the relevant part. Done.

Comment: Would you like a List or what for x? Did you already design the undelying POJO for Vehicle?

Comment: The quality of answers will depends on the quality of your question… Please try to provide all the useful and required information at first shot…

Comment: Please don't forget to validate my answer if my implementation is sufficient to begin with your real implementation…